# Can't connect android emulator to look at local sites and services

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to use an Android emulator to use services running on my local machine. I have a site running under IIS which in my host file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       www.local.company.co.uk
```

I have several sites running under Apache Tomcat. My host file for Tomcat related sites:

```
127.0.0.1       internal.localhost.company.com  # port:8090
127.0.0.2       external.localhost.company.com  # port:8081
127.0.0.3       auth.ws.localhost.company.com  # port:8082
127.0.0.8       mysite.localhost.company.com  # port:8086
```

What I have tried so far (in the following steps):

```
adb pull /etc/hosts
```

Edit Android host file:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
10.0.2.2         myefc.localhost.efinancialcareers.com
```

adb remount
adb push hosts /etc/hosts
Then I try to visit myefc.localhost.efinancialcareers.com in the browser and am told webpage not found. I’d at least expect it to go to www.local.company.co.uk.

What I would ideally like is to be able to go to any site on my local machine which are specified in the above host file examples.

I am on Windows 7 and using Tomcat 6. The emulator I am using is nexus one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the IP address of your server. If you reference localhost from the device it will try to make a connection to itself through the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1.